# How to render an image file which is stored NOT in web application's home folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Imagine there's a web (mvc) application, which home directory on the server is the default `c:\intepub\wwwroot`. What i need is:

1. user requests http://server/randomPicture
2. Server responses with a simple page with a random picture on it from a predefined path, which is **not** iis folder/app, like `d:\lolcats\`

This sample is tremendously simplified, of course. My solution is: when `/randomPicture/` is requested, copy random picture to `APP_Images/current_response.jpg` or whatever to application home folder and then simply render

```
<img src="../APP_Images/current_response.jpg" />
```

Is this the only solution or there's a more civilized way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it but simplest is the least geeky one: Just create a virtual folder for the image location in the IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTTP Handler as follows:

```
    public class GetImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(now.AddYears(1));
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
        context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(now);
        context.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["FileID"] = true;
        context.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);

        context.Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", file.ContentLength.ToString());

        //TODO: Get your file here
        string contentDisposition = String.Empty;
        contentDisposition += "filename=" + file.OriginalFilename;

        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", contentDisposition);
        string imagePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Settings.Default.MediaPath), file.LocalFilename);
        context.Response.WriteFile(imagePath);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<img src="/Handlers/GetImage.ashx?FileID=' + thumbnailFileID + '" alt="" />
```